# Creating different random numbers in array

Tags: c, arrays, random

I want to create an array which has 20 elements and each element holds different integer numbers from closed interval [0-19].

---

Here is the codeblock:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#define SIZE 20

int main() 
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int array[SIZE]={0}, arrayhold[SIZE]={0}, hold, i;

    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++) 
    {
        hold = rand()%20+1;

        if(arrayhold[hold]==0)
        {
            array[i]=hold;
            arrayhold[hold]++;
        }
        else 
        {
            while(arrayhold[hold]!=0)
                hold = rand()%20+1;

            array[i]=hold;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++) 
    {
        printf("array[%d]=%d\n",i,array[i]);
    }
}
```

---

> When I run the program, the output gives array[random]=1 for many times, but it never gives array[random]=3 *(just for example)*.

[Example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bo363.jpg)

Comment: Your code is supposed to write out an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an algorithmic point of view, something like [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) would be perhaps better.

---

Anyway, in the given code

```
arrayhold[hold]++;
```

is missing in `else`. Try

```
else {
    while (arrayhold[hold] != 0)
        hold = rand() % 20 + 1;
    array[i] = hold;
    arrayhold[hold]++; // <--
}
```

Also, either avoid `+ 1` in

```
rand() % 20 + 1
```

to get values from `[0, SIZE-1]` or use `arrayhold[SIZE + 1]`, since currently `arrayhold` is indexed from `1`.

---

In fact, the code can be simplified, `if` is redundant, it would be enough to have just `while` within `for`. (Also, IMO, it would be better to use an assignment instead of `++`.) Consider

```
for (i = 0; i<SIZE; i++) {
    hold = rand() % SIZE + 1;
    while (arrayhold[hold] != 0)
        hold = rand() % 20 + 1;
    array[i] = hold;
    arrayhold[hold] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(arrayhold[hold]!=0)
   hold = rand()%20+1;
array[i]=hold;
```

Here you are iterating until arrayhold[hold] is 0. So you are basically just trying to guess, when hold will be a number, on position of which in `arrayhold` is 0. Apperantly it's 1.

Possible solution is the following:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
    array[i] = rand() % 20 + 1;
    int found = 0;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        if (array[j] == array[i]) {
            found = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found)
        ++i;
}
```

Solution in c++ is using `std::random_shuffle`. You may google for it's implementation and try to translate it into C.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to simplify your logic a bit [Please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup].  This works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SIZE 20

int
main()
{
    int array[SIZE] = { 0 };
    int arrayhold[SIZE] = { 0 };
    int j;
    int i;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        while (1) {
            j = rand() % SIZE;
            if (arrayhold[j] == 0) {
                arrayhold[j] = 1;
                array[i] = j + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        printf("array[%d]=%d\n", i, array[i]);
    }
}
```